# Alternating Series Test Conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm learning about the Alternating Series Test which can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx).

[image]

My question is: Can you give an example of where $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n} = 0$ but $b_{n}$ is an increasing sequence?

Comment: You have to give up the condition that $b_n\ge0$. Then, just change the sign of $b_n$ or reindex the series so that you have $\sum(-1)^{n-1}b_n$. The series $\sum ka_n$ is convergent whenever $\sum a_n$ is, even when $k=-1$.

Comment: Except for the constant sequence $b_n = 0$, a nondecreasing sequence with nonnegative terms cannot converge to $0$. But a sequence with nonnegative terms can converge to $0$ without being monotonic, and that's the point. If $$b_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} &, n \text{ odd} \\ \frac{1}{n^2} &, n \text{ even}, \end{cases}$$ then $\sum (-1)^n b_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: If $b_n \ge 0$ and $\lim b_n = 0$ the only increasing sequence is $b_n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

There is the Generalized Dirichlet Convergence Test. It is similar, but replaces $(-1)^n$ by a sequence with bounded partial sums, and replaces the monotonicity of $b_n$ with bounded variation.

> If $a_n,b_n$ satisfy the following three conditions
>
> 1. $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_n\right|\le A$, independent of $n$.
> 2. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.
> 3. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty|b_{k+1}-b_k|=B\lt\infty$; that is, $b_n$ is of bounded variation.
>
> then
> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_nb_n$$
> converges, and its absolute value does not exceed $AB$.

If $b_n$ tends monotonically to $0$, it satisfies 2. and 3. above, even if $b_n\le0$.